# Symfony, how to read and upload epub file in google storage and read it

Tags: php, symfony, google-cloud-storage, epub

I work with `"symfony/symfony": "~3.4",` and `"knplabs/gaufrette": "^0.3.0",` for uploading media to google storage. But how to be with `epub` files, when I add `epub` file in body `post` request, I had file without name or path

```
epubUrl = {Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile} [7]
 test = false
 originalName = "RU EJTOP epub r1 (2).epub"
 mimeType = "application/octet-stream"
 size = 0
error = 1
*SplFileInfo*pathName = ""
*SplFileInfo*fileName = ""
```

and action catch error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty
```

from upload function, because `file_get_contents` required some path

```
    public function upload(
    UploadedFile $file,
    $target,
    $allowedMimeTypesArray,
    $name
) {
    if (!$allowedMimeTypesArray) {
        $allowedMimeTypesArray = self::$allowedMimeTypes;
    }
    // Check if the file's mime type is in the list of allowed mime types.
    if (!in_array($file->getClientMimeType(), $allowedMimeTypesArray, true)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            sprintf(
                'Files of type %s are not allowed.',
                $file->getClientMimeType()
            )
        );
    }
    $y = file_get_contents($file->getPathname());
    $this->storeFile($target, file_get_contents($file->getPathname()), $name);

    return $name;
}

    private function storeFile($target, $data, $name)
{
    /** @var GoogleCloudStorage $fileSystem */
    $fileSystem = $this->getFileSystem($target);

    if (false === $fileSystem->write($name, $data)) {
        throw new \Exception('Storing file failed');
    }
}
```

how to upload epub file in google storage and then read it ? 
and how it works with epub file in php ?

Comment: Are you sure your upload works properly? Does it work with Word or pure text files?

Comment: @NicoHaase I checked, when upload `txt` or `doc` file in `request` i have file `UploadFile` class with `*SplFileInfo*pathName = "/tmp/phpJKcZTL"
*SplFileInfo*fileName = "phpJKcZTL"`

Comment: You forgot to share your error message. And if you upload a text or word file, everything works?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes, when upload text or world or image everything fine. error message - `Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty`

Answer (score 0):

I found, `php.ini` `upload_max_filesize` after increase it - file uploaded with path and name and get contents and write go google storage. Because need follow errors in UploadedFile class